# jquery mobile fixed footer not at the botton, on windows Phone 7 and 8

Tags: jquery, windows-phone

I am converting my app to also run on Windows Phone 7.x and 8 (it is already running on iPhone and Android).

I have this issue where the footer does not show at the very bottom but sits a little above the end. As you can see on the Picture her: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7685276/Footer%20issue.png

Can any of you help.. 
As I say this is not a issue on Android and iPhone.

It is jQuery 1.9.1, jQueryMobile 1.3, PhoneGap 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the height of the container at MainPage.xaml or you reset the height of the All page content div "i do not know its name with you" to fit the height of the screen

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately that is not a option.. I am using build to build my windows phone app.  But thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You have to change viewport width for all 3 resolutions available in windows phone 8

below code will work for HTC windows phone 8x

Include meta tag in your head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

Include below style in your head section

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    @-ms-viewport { width: 50%; }        
}
```

You need to write this for all 3 resolution available for windows phone 8. You might have to decrease width for higher DPI phones and increase width for lesser DPI phone.

viewport width for Nokia lumia 920 will be around 70-80% and for Nokia Lumia 820 it would be around 85-95%. But you need to find out min width and max width for both these phones.

Answer (score 0):

set the position like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="position: absolute">
```